# How can I change the background color of the left area (not the editor, which is easy!)

Tags: intellij-idea, background-color

I'm struggling to find out how I can change the background color of the left area (project window etc.). To change the editor area is easy, but I can't find the option for the left side. I'm using the newest version of Intellij (2018.2). I found the option for the "file colors", but this does not set the color for t he whole area, but only the project-folder-tree.

Anyone have any clues? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

thats currently (Jan 2019) not supported, but you can upvote the feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68337